# pthread_cond_timedwait does not return in GHC FFI

Tags: c, haskell, posix, mutex, ghc

I've tried to implement Haskell `Control.Concurrent.MVar` that resides in shared memory and allows communicating between multiple independent processes/programs using POSIX functionality.
But I have failed with lots of deadlocks.

The problem is that `pthread_cond_timedwait` sometimes does not return being called within GHC FFI (albeit `interruptible` or `unsafe`).
After a few days of desperate attempts to resolve the problem, I decided to minify the code and ask community to help. Unfortunately, I could not condense the problem into a few lines of code pastable in here. Therefore, I stored the (as small as possible) code on github together with the instructions on how to replicate the problem [here is a permalink](https://github.com/achirkin/interprocess/tree/fc886146dc5eb5600857d6885e31501d562c9c1d) to the current state of it (`mvar-fail` branch).

In the essence, the functions to take and put mvar look like this:

```
int mvar_take(MVar *mvar, ...) {
   pthread_mutex_timedlock(&(mvar->statePtr->mvMut), &timeToWait);
   while ( !(mvar->statePtr->isFull) ) {
     pthread_cond_signal(&(mvar->statePtr->canPutC));
     pthread_cond_timedwait(&(mvar->statePtr->canTakeC), &(mvar->statePtr->mvMut), &timeToWait);
   }
   memcpy(localDataPtr, mvar->dataPtr, mvar->statePtr->dataSize);
   mvar->statePtr->isFull = 0;
   pthread_mutex_unlock(&(mvar->statePtr->mvMut));
}

int mvar_put(MVar *mvar, ...) {
   pthread_mutex_timedlock(&(mvar->statePtr->mvMut), &timeToWait);
   while ( mvar->statePtr->isFull ) {
     pthread_cond_signal(&(mvar->statePtr->canTakeC));
     pthread_cond_timedwait(&(mvar->statePtr->canPutC), &(mvar->statePtr->mvMut), &timeToWait);
   }
   memcpy(mvar->dataPtr, localDataPtr, mvar->statePtr->dataSize);
   mvar->statePtr->isFull = 1;
   pthread_mutex_unlock(&(mvar->statePtr->mvMut));
}
```

(Plus error checking and printfs after every command).
[Full code for `mvar_take`.](https://github.com/achirkin/interprocess/blob/76e109552aee60d4aea7510e9feb5ffc944c59be/src/StoredMVar.c#L274)
The initialization happens as follows:

```
pthread_mutexattr_init(&(s.mvMAttr));
pthread_mutexattr_settype(&(s.mvMAttr), PTHREAD_MUTEX_ERRORCHECK);
pthread_mutexattr_setpshared(&(s.mvMAttr), PTHREAD_PROCESS_SHARED);
pthread_mutex_init(&(s.mvMut), &(s.mvMAttr));
pthread_condattr_init(&(s.condAttr));
pthread_condattr_setpshared(&(s.condAttr), PTHREAD_PROCESS_SHARED);
pthread_cond_init(&(s.canPutC), &(s.condAttr));
pthread_cond_init(&(s.canTakeC), &(s.condAttr));
```

[Full code.](https://github.com/achirkin/interprocess/blob/76e109552aee60d4aea7510e9feb5ffc944c59be/src/StoredMVar.c#L128)
The Haskell part looks like this:

```
foreign import ccall interruptible "mvar_take"
  mvar_take :: Ptr StoredMVarT -> Ptr a -> CInt -> IO CInt
foreign import ccall interruptible "mvar_put"
  mvar_put :: Ptr StoredMVarT -> Ptr a -> CInt -> IO CInt

takeMVar :: Storable a => StoredMVar a -> IO a
takeMVar (StoredMVar _ fp) = withForeignPtr fp $ \p -> alloca $ \lp -> do
    r <- mvar_take p lp
    if r == 0
    then peek lp
    else throwErrno $ "takeMVar failed with code " ++ show r

putMVar :: Storable a => StoredMVar a -> a -> IO ()
putMVar (StoredMVar _ fp) x = withForeignPtr fp $ \p -> alloca $ \lp -> do
    poke lp x
    r <- mvar_put p lp
    unless (r == 0)
      $ throwErrno $ "putMVar failed with code " ++ show r
```

[Full code.](https://github.com/achirkin/interprocess/blob/76e109552aee60d4aea7510e9feb5ffc944c59be/src/wait-mvar.hs#L174-L214)
Changing FFI from `interruptible` to `unsafe` does not prevent the deadlock.
Sometimes the deadlock happens every second run, sometimes it happens after 50 runs only (and the rest is executed as expected).

My guess is that GHC might interfere the work of POSIX mutexes with some OS signal handling, but I don't know GHC internals enough to verify it.

Is that me doing something stupidly wrong, or do I need to add some special tricks to make it work inside GHC FFI?

**P.S.:** the last version of README with my investigations is available at [`interprocess mvar-fail`](https://github.com/achirkin/interprocess/blob/mvar-fail/README.md).

**UPDATE 13.06.2018**:
I tried to temporarily block all OS signals by surrounding function code with following:

```
sigset_t mask, omask;
sigfillset(&mask);
sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, &mask, &omask);
...
sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, &omask, NULL);
```

This did not help.

Comment: Also, please, comment if you don't know what the problem is, but managed (or not managed) to reproduce the bug on your machine (and tell OS/kernel version).

Comment: have you used a bound thread? is your ffi code guaranteed to return using the same OS thread when it blocks?

Comment: have you taken a look  at https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/Commentary/Rts/Signals with regards to signals?

Comment: In particular, consider using `pthread_sigmask()` ?

Comment: @user239558 yes, I tried first `forkIO`, then changed it to `forkOS`. Not sure for the latter question; could you elaborate? My FFI code does not do any thread manipulation - only mutex functions.

Comment: @sclv , thanks for suggestion. Yes, I looked at that and tried to play with `pthread_sigmask`, but I am afraid don't have enough experience with `pthread` to understand well the commentary and write a proper signal masking/unmasking. I am also afraid it can break `interruptible` behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, as expected, this was my fault - a very C-beginner error.
As one can see from the initialization snippet, I keep the mutex and the condition variables in a structure.
What one cannot see from the snippet here, but can see by the links I gave (on github), is that I am copying that structure to a shared memory. Not only that is not allowed for mutexes, but I also stupidly copy it before I initialize everything in the structure.

That is, I just [copied a C structure](https://github.com/achirkin/interprocess/blob/mvar-fail/src/StoredMVar.c#L116) where I should have set a pointer.

The most surprising here is that the code still works sometimes.
[Here is the link to the erroneous code.](https://github.com/achirkin/interprocess/blob/mvar-fail/src/StoredMVar.c#L111-L155)